# Finding Null Space Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

let $v$ be a vector $v=(1,-1,1)$, find $Ker(v)$ or $v*x=0$

I have approached it this way 
$(y-z,-y,z)=(y,-y,0)+(-z,0,z)=y(1,-1,0)+z(-1,0,1)$

But the answer  $(1,1,0),(-1,0,1)$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: How do you define the kernel of a vector?

Comment: Ker(V): $v*x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to compute a basis for the nullspace of the matrix
$$
v=\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
To do so, note that $\DeclareMathOperator{null}{null}\vec x\in\null v$ if and only if
$$
x_1-x_2+x_3=0
$$
It follows that $\vec x\in\null v$ if and only if
$$
\vec x
= \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\\ -x_1+x_2\end{bmatrix} 
= x_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}+x_2\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
This proves that the vectors $\langle 1,0,-1\rangle$ and $\langle 0,1,1\rangle$ span $\null v$. It is also clear that $\langle 1,0,-1\rangle$ and $\langle 0,1,1\rangle$ are linearly independent. Hence $\langle 1,0,-1\rangle$ and $\langle 0,1,1\rangle$ form a basis for $\null v$.

Comment: Cant I choose to express $x_2$ using $x_1,x_3$? and not $x_3$?

Comment: @gbox Sure. You can express any of the three in terms of the other two. Keep in mind that bases are not unique so there are infinitely many answers to your question.

Comment: Just to make sure, I can express any of the three with the two others? so  $x_1$ been a pivot column, does not limit my selection?

Comment: @gbox Of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're actually doing is finding the orthogonal complement of $\langle (1, -1, 1) \rangle$.  You're trying to find vectors perpendicular to $v$, so let $(x,y,z)$ be such a vector.  Then we have $x - y + z = 0$, which implies $y = x+ z$  You're thus looking for vectors of the form $(x,x + z,z)$.  This is a subspace of dimension $2$, so you can pick any two linearly independent vectors of the form $(x,x+z,z)$.  The given answer works, but so does $\{(1,1,0), (0,1,1)\}$ and many, many other choices.

Comment: The question started with a 3 by 3 matrix but after row operations, it came up to this 1 equation

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^n$, you have an equation of the form:

$$a-b+c=0 \iff a+c=b$$

Thence $\ker L_v$, where we define $L_v$ to be the linear map:

$$L_v: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, w \mapsto \langle v,w \rangle,$$

is given by the set:

$$\{w \in \mathbb{R}^3 | (w=(a, a+c, c)^T ) \wedge (a,b,c \in \mathbb{R})\}$$

Notice that $\mathbb{R}$ could be any field were a non-degenerate inner product exists.